# How do I load test with multiple socket connections using Jmeter?

Tags: testing, websocket, jmeter, load-testing

Also if I have authorisation header fields-> Where and how do I give them?? Is there any tool for this?

I have done local host "ws://localhost:8080/socket" using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the ["WebSockets Samplers"](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src) plugin with JMeter, you can open multiple websocket connections, but not at the same time on the same thread (JMeter user). If you are sure you need that feature, there is an experimental build of the plugin that supports multiple connections on one thread.
You can add authorisation fields by using the standard JMeter HeaderManager.